# C# XNA pass by reference classes in constructor

Tags: c#, xna, pass-by-reference

I'm making a vector graphics game in XNA. I've designed a Line class to rotate around a central point to help draw specific shapes. In order to maintain a single point of truth, is there a way to pass a reference to the center of the shape to all of the lines I create, so that updating the center's position will also update the lines' positions? I thought something like this would work:

```
class Line
{
    private Vector2 start;
    private double length;
    private double angle;

    public Line(ref Vector2 start, double length, double angle){
        this.start = start;
        this.length = length;
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}




class Obj
{
    private Vector2 center;
    private Line[] lines;
    public Obj(){
        center = new Vector2(50,50);
        lines = new Lines[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            lines[i] = new Line(ref center,30, (i/5 * 2 * Math.PI));

        }

    }
}
```

but the lines do not update when I move the center. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the `struct` is correctly passed by reference to `Line`, when you assign it internally:

```
public Line(ref Vector2 start, double length, double angle){
    this.start = start;
}
```

You are actually taking a *copy* of the `struct`.

If you ever find yourself needing reference type semantics of `struct` beyond passing it to a single method then you likely need to reconsider using `class`.

You can either re-implement the type in a class or wrap the `Vector2` in a class and use that:

```
class Vector2Class
{
    public Vector2 Centre;

    public Vector2Class(Vector2 inner)
    {
        Centre = inner;
    }
}

class Line
{
    private Vector2Class _centre;

    public Line(Vector2Class centre)
    {
        _centre = centre;    
    }
}
```

Be aware that you are still working against a copy, but if you share the class you'll all be working on the *same* copy.

Personally, I would **avoid** the wrapper and make my own class for representing "centre". This is supported by the largely accepted idea that `struct` types should be immutable, but you seem to need to mutate the values to keep the representation true.

```
class CentreVector<T>
{
    public <T> X { get; set; }
    public <T> Y { get; set; }
}
```

This only lets you share the data, it doesn't actually *notify* the lines that the centre has changed. For that you would need some sort of event.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited with alternative solution**

The problem you're having is because Vector2 is a value type, you're correctly passing it by ref in your methods parameter but then making a local copy of it with the assignment.

I'm not totally sure if you could maintain a pointer to Vector2 in the way that you're thinking but you could create your own Vector2 class that would be a reference type.

```
class ObjectVector2
{
    public float X { get;set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to suggest a slightly different way to achieve the same result by holding a reference to the obj that the lines are a part of.

```
class Line
{

    private Vector2 Center { get { return parent.center; } }
    private double length;
    private double angle;
    Obj parent;

    public Line(Obj parent, double length, double angle)
    {
       this.parent = parent;
       this.length = length;
       this.angle = angle;
    }
}

class Obj
{
    public Vector2 center;
    private Line[] lines;
    public Obj()
    {
        center = new Vector2(50, 50);
        lines = new Lines[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           // passing the reference to this Obj in the line constructor.
           lines[i] = new Line(this, 30, (i / 5 * 2 * Math.PI));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could create a simple class StructWrapper<T> which would be more general purpose. (this is similar to boxing)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't actually like to create a new Vector2 since there are quite a few methods that use Vector2 and conversions are required, better to hold the ref to the parent object and use it's properties.

Comment: You could also go for an event-based approach where the parent object raises an event when the centre point changes. Not sure how popular event-based models are in games though :)